# CSS how to get a div to the right side and a div exactly in the middle?

Tags: css

I got a div but that's now covering the whole thing atm. I want the div to be exactly in the middle(like at this website), + a div extra at the right side, that covers all the space left on the right side of the div in the middle. So only the left side should be blank. How do i do this? Here is my css code:

```
.header{

position:relative;
z-index:10;
text-align: center;
width:1900;
height:100;
background-size:100%;

font-size: 36px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Brush Script Std ;
background-color:#C0C0C0;
}

.middle{
width:1000;
float:middle;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
height:819;
border:50px;
}

.right{
font-size: 36px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Brush Script Std ;
float: right;
width: 300;
margin-left: -200px;
height: 818;
background-color:#C0C0C0;
}

.footer{
text-align: center;
height:50px;
width: 1900px;
background-color:#C0C0C0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant float:middle. Use margin:auto to center a block.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a fiddle that seems to fix it.

http://jsfiddle.net/JKNyw/

I changed the float:middle to margin:auto and i added "px" where it was missing. (a few of your height/width were just numbers without 'px')¨
before

```
width:300;
```

after

```
width:300px;
```